# What software can I use to create a indoor map and see it on iPhone?

Tags: iphone, google-maps, localization, mapping, gps

I want to create a inside building map with multiple levels (building floors), directions (navigation), coordinates and statical locations (elevators, escalators, emergency exits, etc) but I don't know what software can I use for that.

Also I want to include this map on a iPhone app so other users can see it and interact with it. I don't know if it's possible to use Google Maps API to doing that.

I could use a image in Illustrator or Dreamweaver to create a image map, but I think that isn't a good option to update data (layout changes often).

Thank you very much!!!

Answer (score 3):

I'll answer the question I asked three years ago, as this can help other StackOverflow users seeking answers to the same question.

Currently there are several tools that can be used to create indoor maps for iOS (iPhone and iPad) apps.

There are two tools that IMHO are the best options, and they have different approaches, as follows:

https://www.indooratlas.com/ - Indoor atlas detects variations to magnetic fields inside buildings to better identifies user's position. You can use smartphones (iPhone and Android) to sense and record these magnetic variations and to map indoor locations.

http://indoo.rs/ - Using iBeacons you can develop indoor maps and guide users with routes inside small our large buildings like malls, universities, museums, etc.

Both tools have APIs that you can use on your apps.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you need to decide how you want to deliver it. You indicate that it's not just on an iPhone and given it's a building map it probably changes a lot. So I'd be suggesting you look into doing it as a web site. If you go that way there are a whole range of technologies that you can employ to construct a web site. But basically there are two pieces you would need to research and consider. That being the technologies you want to employ on the web server to generate the site, and the technologies you want to use on the client (browser) to view the site.

I'd suggest searching for other similar sites and looking at how they do them. This can tell you two things - what works and what doesn't work.

Lastly you need to consider your strengths, what programming languages do you know? Is it practical for you to learn new languages and technologies for this? What's your budget like? Can you afford to contract the work? etc.